# Я не видел девушку(,) по-настоящему красивую

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Я не видел девушку(,) по-настоящему красивую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Существительное *девушку* не выражает без определения нужного смысла, оно нуждается в нëм**:

*Я не видел девушку по-настоящему красивую*.

Запятая не нужна; см. [«Розенталя», пункт 2-2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108).

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

*Я не видел дЕвушку, **по-настоящему красИвую.***

Без обособления предложение не имеет смысла. В данном случае семантика такая:

*Я еще не видел дЕвушку, **которая была бы по-настоящему красИва.***

Comment: Зачем обособлять? Правило у Максима.

Comment: Мне не нужны правила, если я вижу, что предложение неправильное.  А вы уж по правилам работайте. ИСТОРИЯ. Идет по-настоящему красивая девушка, а я ее не вижу. А друг вот увидел и познакомился..,

Comment: Ну тогда давай е обособлять любое предложение, которое нам захочется.

Comment: Серж, у вас должны быть правильные желания. Именно для этого существуют правила и грамматика. А здесь я про чувство языка.  Оно есть у каждого.  И вот мое чувство подсказывает мне: неправильное предложение! Я не видел и я еще не видел - разное время, различать надо.